# Set more than one font feature in gb4e

Tags: beamer, fonts, linguistics, gb4e

I'm trying to get in gb4e glosses the first line to be in bold roman font but I can only set roman or bold, not both. How can I set both?

The document is a beamer presentation with a sans serif font as default font. I tried these, but they don't work:

```
\let\eachwordone=\textbf{\rmfamily}
```

and

```
\let\eachwordone=\rmfamily\bf
```

What I get is just \bf with the first code and just roman with the second.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The two letter font commands are deprecated, and have been replaced.  Your second attempt was on the right track but you needed to use `\bfseries` instead of `\bf`.  But also the syntax of TeX `\let` only allows a single token after the `=`; to do what you want you should use the LaTeX `\renewcommand` instead.

Furthermore, if you want to change the font of the translation line also, you will need to use a different method, since `gb4e` provides no built-in hook for that. In the example below I've used the `\pretocmd` from the `etoolbox` package to modify the `\glt` macro (whose synonym is `\trans`).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\renewcommand{\eachwordone}{\rmfamily\bfseries}
\pretocmd{\glt}{\rmfamily}{}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{exe}
\ex{
\gll This is the first line\\
     This is the second line\\
\glt This is the translation
}
\label{ex}
\end{exe}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Personally, however, I would not mix serif and sans serif fonts in a `beamer` presentation, so a simpler way would be just to use `\usefonttheme{serif}` and then define just `\eachwordone` to be `\bfseries`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\renewcommand{\eachwordone}{\bfseries}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{exe}
\ex{
\gll This is the first line\\
     This is the second line\\
\glt This is the translation
}
\label{ex}
\end{exe}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

If you would prefer all the text to be in the sans serif font to match the default `beamer` fonts, you will need to change each of the macros that determine the font for the gloss lines.  These are `\eachwordone`, `\eachwordtwo` and `\eachwordthree`.  So to get all gloss lines in sans serif you add

```
\renewcommand{\eachwordone}{\sffamily}
\renewcommand{\eachwordtwo}{\sffamily}
\renewcommand{\eachwordthree}{\sffamily}
```

Comment: Thanks Alan! Luckily my presentation is just an introduction to XeLaTeX. I'm using DejaVu fonts but they don't have true small caps. That is why I'm mixing typefaces. Do you know a sans font with IPA support, italics, bold, and small caps?

Comment: @Stefano Sans serif IPA fonts are quite rare; SIL Sophia was one, but it doesn't seem to be supported by SIL anymore.  I think the IPA was designed with a serifed font in mind, and adaptations to sans serif faces are always weak.

Comment: For me, `gb4e` mixes serif and sans serif fonts, so that I get the example and the gloss in a serif font, and the translation in a sans serif font. Instead of using `\usefonttheme{serif}`, I'd like my whole presentation to use the sans serif font. Is there a way to change `gb4e` to achieve this?

Comment: @SebastianSulger I've updated the answer to show you how to achieve uniform sans serif glosses.