# Control gb4e's font family selection

Tags: beamer, fonts, sans-serif, gb4e

In `beamer`, the default font is sans serif. But `gb4e` will override this default and select a serif font for both the line to be glossed (introduced with `\gll`) and the glosses. Only the translation line will be sans serif. How can I control the font families chosen by `gb4e` so that I can get sans serif in every line?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
    \setsansfont{Latin Modern Sans}
    \setmonofont{Latin Modern Mono}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{exe}
\ex
    \gll f g f g\\ % this appears as serif
    f g f g\\ % this appears as serif
    \trans f g f g. % this appears as sans serif
\end{exe}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(My bet is that something like this has been asked before, but I haven't been able to find a duplicate).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
    \setsansfont{Latin Modern Sans}
    \setmonofont{Latin Modern Mono}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\let\eachwordone=\sffamily %or \normalfont
\let\eachwordtwo=\sffamily
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{exe}
\ex
    \gll f g f g\\ % this appears as serif
    f g f g\\ % this appears as serif
    \trans f g f g. % this appears as sans serif
\end{exe}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry to interrupt, but how do you change font size for `gb4e` examples? It doesn't seem to react to  what you write in `\documentclass`.

Comment: This solution does not allow small caps in the gloss line.

Comment: @Eline Latin Modern Sans doesn't have small caps, you will have to use another font.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, can you suggest a sans serif font with small caps (and preferably IPA)? I see other people have asked (e.g. in comments [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/185553/set-more-than-one-font-feature-in-gb4e#comment429067_185560)) but I haven't seen an answer.

Comment: no, sorry. Call (assuming that you have a current texsystem) on a command line `albatross 0x025D`  (or other unicode code point numbers from IPA) , this should give a list of fonts on your system supporting the symbol, and then check the font.